# How to add a "derived" column in superset with druid?

Tags: apache-superset, druid

There is a "__time" field (in milliseconds) in the raw druid schema, while now I need add several "derived" fields to day|month|year of "__time" to be grouped by, how to add them in superset "List Druid Column" tab?[image]

Comment: may be try having the derived fields also in your raw data

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the description below "Dimension Spec JSON" you have to define a valid Dimension Spec as specified in [druid docs](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/dimensionspecs.html), have a look at the section "Time Format Extraction Function", there is an example that suits you.

Make sure to add the extranction JSON as a Druid Column and not a Druid Metric, and the name in the JSON and the name of the column match!